# Univariate Regression, expectation of x given y

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation

Perhaps an easy question for some: Given I have a univariate regression setting... $$y = b_1*x + e$$ ... with $e$ being the normally distributed error (standard normal dist.). $x$ is also a random variable which follows a standard normal distribution. How do I find the conditional expectation of x given y? $$E(x|y)$$

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate of another question that gives an in-depth answer to a similar question. If it does not answer your question, feel free to edit your question on what exactly is not clear for you and what kind of help do you need.

Comment: Thanks, the linked question helped me solve my problem.